# Share properties and *.tag files between different webapps

Tags: spring, web-applications, properties, share

I have 3 webapps (webapp1,webapp2,webapp3) and I want to share message.properties files (and also .tag) between them.
webapp3 should act as "common" webapp container files.
I tried putting shared files in the "webapp3/resources" folder, "webapp3/WEB-INF" folder but webapp1 and webapp2 cannot access them.

How can I group props and tag files in the webapp3 structure?

I'm using Spring 3.1